# How to run Selenium Script (Junit) from Jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins

I'm encountering some issues by executing Selenium Scripts from Jenkins, I'm totally beginner so I need many explanations if somenone can provide some...

- So i'm running Jenkins on my VM Linux.
- I've got those selenium script in a folder of this VM.

What should I do to manage to make in run through Jenkins ?

I don't understand a lot so if you could give me as much as details as possible...

- If I have to use maven, what are the configurations in Jenkins ? Do i have to create a POM.xml ? If yes what to insert inside ? Where do I put it ?
- If that's not the solution ? what should I do ?

Thanks in advance ! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Junit tests run properly on your workstation, then you must do the following:

- Ensure your application gets started your application (if you have a Java application, use for instance Maven Jetty Plugin (http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Jetty_Maven_Plugin). You can tight that to the `integration-test` if you use Maven Failsafe plugin
- You'll need to start an fake X server before the job starts: use Xvfb Jenkins plugin (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Xvfb+Plugin)
- You'll need the correct WebDriver for your browser, for Google Chrome, see https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver

http://alex.nederlof.com/blog/2012/11/19/installing-selenium-with-jenkins-on-ubuntu/ provides setup details.

Comment: Ok thanks, but should i not just edit a pom.xml explaining dependencies and anythins else ?

Comment: Of course, if you don't have Maven configuration at all, then you'll need to create one. The bits and pieces I describe assume that you already have a working Maven configuration for everything but you Selenium tests. To have this on Jenkins, you should edit the pom.xml to configure maven jetty plugin and maven failsafe plugin, the rest of the configuration is made is Jenkins specific.

Comment: Ok thanks for those informations, I got a new question, I know got success on Jenkins but i think jenkins doesn't really execute my file.java
i guess it's information i have to indicate in the <build> of my POM.
But what are those ?

Comment: To give more details for my  "maven-compiler-plugin", I got the message : "No sources to compile", but how to indicate thoses sources?

Comment: Directories Maven looks for files are by default `src/main/java` and `src/test/java`